# How do I format a number left-padded without using String.format in Java 6?

Tags: java, binary, padding

For example, I need to grab an unknown number, let's say 3, and find the binary (2^3) - 1 times, from 0 to 111 (0-7). Obviously, the number of digits I need depends on whatever number 'n' in 2^n.

So, if the number is 3, I would need the output to be:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
111
```

Now obviously I can do this manually with a String.format("%03d", NumberInBinary) operation, but that's hardcoding it for 3 digits. I need to do the equivalent code with an unknown number of digits, how can I do that? (as in String.format("%0nd", yournumber) where n is the number of digits.)

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625838/java-specify-number-of-bits-length-when-converting-binary-number-to-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if n = 4, NumberInBinary = 101;

```
String.format("%0"+n+"d", NumberInBinary);
```

with output

```
0101
```

Comment: this doesn't cover the enumeration and binary conversion aspect.

Comment: also, I don't see what NumberInBinary would be for this to work.

Comment: @Matthew read the question completly first. n and NumberInBinary are already available for the OP. he just needs to print it.

Comment: @Matthew just output binary value, not find.

Comment: StackOverflowException is correct, I have already found the binary number. And his solution worked perfectly, I had no idea you could do that, and it makes perfect sense since the inside of the quotes are treated as a String, so doing "%0"+n+"d" did the trick perfectly, adapting itself to every case. Thanks, brother. And thanks Matthew, you also helped me learn of an alternate method of finding the binary value. I just used a for loop, starting at int i = 0, going up until 2^n - 1, getting 'i', using Integer.toString(i, 2), parsing it, and outputting it using StackOverflowExceptions's method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of the already built-in Integer.toBinaryString() and just manually add the zeros using a StringBuilder ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        if (binary.length() > max) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println( prefixWithZeros(binary, max) );
    }
}

static String prefixWithZeros(String binary, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - binary.length(); i++) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    return sb.append(binary).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```
public static void enumerate(String prefix, int remaining) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        enumerate(prefix + "0", remaining - 1);
        enumerate(prefix + "1", remaining - 1);
    }
}
```

and then call `enumerate("", numberOfDigits);`

faster, using StringBuffer:

```
public static void enumerate(StringBuffer prefix, int remaining) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix.toString());
    } else {
        enumerate(prefix.append('0'), remaining - 1);
        prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);
        enumerate(prefix.append('1'), remaining - 1);
        prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

and then call `enumerate(new StringBuffer(), numberOfDigits);`