# Converting a Hex String into 32 Bit Binary String

Tags: java, string, binary

How can I convert a Hex String into 32bit Binary String? I did

```
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hexAddr, 16));
```

To get the Binary String, but I need to pad it with 0's to ensure its 32 bits, how can I do that, preferably with Formatter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Java) Specify number of bits (length) when converting binary number to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625838/java-specify-number-of-bits-length-when-converting-binary-number-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hexAddr, 16)); 
String.format("%032", new BigInteger(binAddr));
```

The idea here is to parse the string back in as a decimal number temporarily (one that just so happens to consist of all 1's and 0's) and then use `String.format()`.

Note that you basically have to use BigInteger, because binary strings quickly overflow Integer and Long resulting in NumberFormatExceptions if you try to use `Integer.fromString()` or `Long.fromString()`.